# Using window Builder for Android Apps

Tags: android

I am a beginner.
I want to develop an application that its Gui has 3 columns.
On the screen, the user see's 2 left most columns and can swipe, in order to see the middle and the right most columns.
what is the best way to do it? 
Can i use Window Builder for Android Apps, Or is it for desk top Apps Only.
If yes, How Do I open an android project, that uses window builder.
TX

Taly